# How do I get Mockito mocks to cause a failure when unexpected calls are made?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have some mock objects that are probably going to get passed around a bit and might end up being fairly complex.

I'd like to either have Mockito output a log for each call made to a mock or I'd like it to fail whenever an unexpected call is made so I can iterate through those calls and set up appropriate responses.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why not just verify the mock?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most-idiomatic way of doing this is with [`verifyNoMoreInteractions`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verifyNoMoreInteractions(java.lang.Object...)), as in [Mockito docs #8](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Mockito.html#8):

```
//interactions
mock.doSomething();
mock.doSomethingUnexpected();

//verification
verify(mock).doSomething();
 
//following will fail because 'doSomethingUnexpected()' is unexpected
verifyNoMoreInteractions(mock);
```

I say "most-idiomatic" above because that method has its own warning label, which links to the blog post ["Should I worry about the unexpected?"](https://web.archive.org/web/20081207035341/https://monkeyisland.pl/2008/07/12/should-i-worry-about-the-unexpected/) by Mockito originator Szczepan Faber (still visible at a [different URL](https://szczepiq.wordpress.com/2008/07/12/should-i-worry-about-the-unexpected/)).

> `verifyNoMoreInteractions()` is not recommended to use in every test method. `verifyNoMoreInteractions()` is a handy assertion from the interaction testing toolkit. Use it only when it's relevant. Abusing it leads to **overspecified, less maintainable** tests.

In short, you should have a very clear reason to check what your dependency is *not doing* or what your system-under-test is *not calling*, as opposed to what they are doing and calling. You might use `verifyNoMoreInteractions` for an RPC object, if you want to avoid unnecessary RPC calls, but not (say) a calculator with no side effects. Even better is to specify your exact requirements with `never()` or `times(int)` as parameters to `verify`.

---

That said, there are two even-less-idiomatic ways of doing this:

- You can take an overall log of calls made using [`mockingDetails(Object)`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mockingDetails(java.lang.Object)) and iterating through [`getInvocations()`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/MockingDetails.html#getInvocations()). That should reflectively give you a whole list of the invocations. I have a hard time imagining how this would be useful in a test, but it might be useful in cleaning up a nebulous or poorly-documented existing system.
- You can make the mock's default action to throw an exception, which means that if anyone calls something that you haven't stubbed, the test will immediately fail.

  ```
  // untested pseudocode
  YourObject yourObject = Mockito.mock(YourObject.class, withSettings()
      .defaultAnswer(invocation -> {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(invocation.toString());
      }));
  ```

  Sure, that'd work, but you'd not only be violating one of Mockito's core principles ([mocks are *nice* by default](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ#what-values-do-mocks-return-by-default), using [EasyMock's definition of "nice"](http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/EasyMock.html#createNiceMock-java.lang.Class-)), but you'd also force yourself to only stub using `doVerb` (`doReturn`, `doAnswer`, etc) because calls to `when(yourObject.doAnything())` would necessarily throw that exception before the call to `when` would even run.

  Developers who are familiar with Mockito would likely say that this exception-prone cure is worse than the disease, and may be useful only for temporarily diagnosing the most tangled legacy code.

Comment: `verifyNoMoreInteractions()` is so rarely useful, because by the time you can get back to your test method to call it, the component under test has already gone on to try to do something with the `null` it got out of the unexpected call. The default action solution is definitely what the OP wanted.

Comment: @PaulZ I see your point but I'm not as sure that the Answer wins so clearly. If there are existing `when` stubs they'd have to all be rewritten to `doVerb`. Furthermore, the fast-fail method would also mean that you fail once per unstubbed call: If your tests are cheap to run, that's no issue, but if your tests are slow to start (heavy DB, CI server, etc) you might prefer to see all unstubbed interactions in a batch as `verifyNoMoreInteractions(...)` or `getInvocations()` allows.

Comment: I was able to still use `when(...).thenReturn(...)` by writing a defaultAnswer that returned null if a static boolean was not set, and thew an exception if it was set. I set up the mocks with the boolean set to false, then set it to true and ran the method being tested, and it showed me what the missing method I needed to mock was. Very hacky, but I only used it to diagnose, then removed it all once I had a working test.

Answer (score 3):

I was just asking myself the same question and... The solution using ReturnsSmartNulls will return SmartNulls instead of null... So it is meaningful for non-void methods only right ? What about void methods, the ones having side effects ?

In my opinion, if you want to make sure that your test fails when a method of your mock is called without your explicit behavior definition of it (*doXXX(...).when(...)* mockito methods) you can initialize your mocks with a custom default answer that will throw an exception, or better... fail your test.

For example you can add the following class inside your test class (or outside if you intend to use it elsewhere, or even use a MockitoConfiguration class as previously mentionned depending on what you want):

```
static class FailAnswer implements Answer<Object> {

    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        String methodName = invocation.getMethod().getName();
        String className = invocation.getMethod().getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName();
        throw new AssertionError(String.format("%s#%s should not have been called", className, methodName));
    }
}
```

Then init your mock with this fake answer in your setUp method :

```
 @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        delegateService = mock(DelegateService.class, new FailAnswer());
        classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest(delegateService);
    }
```

Unfortunately, this solution is not compatible with @Mock annotation which only takes native predefined answers from org.mockito.Answers enum as argument. So that forces you to manually init every mock, spy, captor within the setUp method (RIP MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this))

Benefit :

- you get rid of default behavior of mockito mocks, sometimes hidding unintentionnal uses of mocks for specifics use cases (does is really matter ?)
  => You must define everything you use (inside tests or tests fixtures)
  => you don't have to make verification to make sure your test have not invoked methods it shouldn't have.

Drawbacks :

- This is an unusual usage of mockito, so this makes your test less affordable
- You give up on MockitoAnnotations feature
- As you override mockito default stubbing, you must use the stubbing form do().when() instead of when(...).do(....), the latter providing au type-checking unlike the former.

Warning : This solution doesn't garantee your mock is called, it just garantees that the method you don't stub won't be called. It doesn't come as replacement for counting methods invocations neither.

Answer (score 2):

The best answer I found is to configure Mockito to return **SmartNulls**.

https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.9/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_SMART_NULLS

> This implementation can be helpful when working with legacy code. Unstubbed methods often return null. If your code uses the object returned by an unstubbed call you get a NullPointerException. This implementation of Answer returns SmartNull instead of null. SmartNull gives nicer exception message than NPE because it points out the line where unstubbed method was called. You just click on the stack trace.

You can do it by mock or by default (might cause problems with other frameworks like Spring).

**Manually**

```
Writer writerMock = mock(Writer.class, RETURNS_SMART_NULLS);
```

**Annotation**

```
@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_SMART_NULLS)
```

**Set as Global Default**

Configuration class must be in exactly this package. This might lead to strange failures with Spring.

```
package org.mockito.configuration;

import org.mockito.internal.stubbing.defaultanswers.ReturnsSmartNulls;
import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;

public class MockitoConfiguration extends DefaultMockitoConfiguration {

    public Answer<Object> getDefaultAnswer() {
        return new ReturnsSmartNulls();
    }
}
```

See: https://solidsoft.wordpress.com/2012/07/02/beyond-the-mockito-refcard-part-1-a-better-error-message-on-npe-with-globally-configured-smartnull/

I had problems with SpringBootRepositories and @MockBean when enabling the global default:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.mockito.codegen.Object$MockitoMock$191495750 cannot be cast to xxx.xxx.MyObject
```

**Example of error output**

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[DataRecordType{id=null, name='SomeRecord', pathTemplate='SomeTemplate'}]> but was:<[SmartNull returned by this unstubbed method call on a mock: dataRecordTypeRepository bean.getById(1L);]>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to track the flow, you can use Mockito verify to check if certain call has been made.

```
verify(yourMockedObject).yourMethod();
```

you can also use times to verify if certain call has to be made exactly some number of times.

```
verify(yourMockedObject, times(4)).yourMethod();
```

It is not a good practice to make your unit test complex. Try to test only small unit of your code at a time.